# No package epel-release available

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel7

I was trying to install epel-release in a freshly set RHEL 7. By the following command

```
yum -y install epel-release
```

And the output was following:

[no package epel-release available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KmAV.png)

What was the reason of this error, and how can I install epel-release?

I was trying to install it so that I could use it to get dnf in my machine. What are effective steps to install it?

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/#_el7):

```
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-*-optional-rpms \
                           --enable rhel-*-extras-rpms \
                           --enable rhel-ha-for-rhel-*-server-rpms
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: I tried to do that already. The first command gives me the following output, showing an error:
"socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known"

Comment: @Jd_mahmud you should deal with that error first then. It seems it can't resolve one of the redhat's domain names, although unfortunately it doesn't say which one. Does DNS generally work on that machine? Check the settings.